# jsDelivr is not updating

Tags: github, cdn, jsdelivr

I know same question exists in stack overflow. However they are not properly answered.

I uploaded a js from Github to jsDelivr. The one in Github is updated but jsDelivr is not.

#### Example:

**Github**

```js
if (event.key === "Enter") {
  let nn = document.getElementById("inputcountryname").value;
  localStorage.setItem("localcountry", nn);
  alert("Your country's name is: " + nn);
  hide("entercountryname");
}
```

**jsDelivr**

```js
if (event.key === "Enter") {
  let nn = document.getElementById("inputcountryname").value;
  localStorage.setItem("localcountry", nn);
  alert("Your country's name is: " + nn);
}
```